# How do I connect a menuType to another viewcontroller?

Tags: swift, button, uiviewcontroller, menu

I want to make the below .merchant menu option link to another view controller I made the UI design for, non-modally. I have a feeling it has something to do with Subview and connecting my MerchantViewController. I do not want to add buttons and I want to use these "cases". Thanks so much, first post.

The possible childviewcontroller solution is mentioned in this video: https://youtu.be/vKh1b3ctCf4?t=556

```
func transitionToNew(_ menuType: MenuType) {
        topView?.removeFromSuperview()
        switch menuType {
        case .profile:
            let view = UIView()
            view.backgroundColor = .yellow
            view.frame = self.view.bounds
            self.view.addSubview(view)
            self.topView = view
        
        case .camera:
            let view = UIView()
            view.backgroundColor = .blue
            view.frame = self.view.bounds
            self.view.addSubview(view)
            self.topView = view
        
        //I want .merchant to link to a MerchantViewController
        case .merchant:
            let view = UIView()
            //view.backgroundColor = .blue
            view.frame = self.view.bounds
            self.view.addSubview(view)
            self.topView = view
        
        default:
            break
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add the Merchant ViewController as a child of the current View Controller.

```
let merchantVC = MerchantViewController()  //setup MerchantViewController
let merchantView = merchantVC.view
self.view.addSubview(merchantView)
self.addChild(merchantVC)
merchantVC.didMove(toParent: self)
self.topView = merchantView
```

Comment: 1) I had to change 
self.view.addSubview(merchantView)
to 
self.view.addSubview(merchantView!)

because I was getting a (Value of optional type 'UIView?' must be unwrapped to a value of type 'UIView') Error

2) I am wondering what you mean by //setup MerchantViewController. I have a storyboard MerchantViewController setup. But this code hasn't worked for me yet.

Comment: The implementation of MerchantViewController was not posted, so I don't know how MerchantViewController should be initialized, hence the comment saying setup MerchantViewController. If you are using storyboard, then replace the first line with `let merchantVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(identifier: <Identifier>) as! MerchantViewController`